# TabLayout tabs text not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I am using `TabLayout` inside a `Fragment` to display three fixed tabs and the tabs are working but it doesn't show the tab text even after I set the `app:tabTextColor` attribute in the layout it's still not visible.

*NewFragment.java*

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return inflatedView;
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentTab();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTab();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentTab();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
}
```

*newfragment.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".NewFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: If anyone is using `TabLayoutMediator`, kindly refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060298/14784590 , use `tab.text=`

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `setupWithViewPager()` after setting up your tabs with the `addTab()` calls, effectively overwriting them.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) of `TabLayout` regarding `setupWithViewPager()`:

> The tabs displayed in this
>   layout will be populated from the `ViewPager` adapter's page titles.

If you would like to use your `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager`, you should override `getPageTitle()` in your `PagerAdapter` (and remove the `addTab()` calls, they are redundant).

For example:

```
public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    // tab titles
    private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};

    public ExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // overriding getPageTitle()
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1Fragment();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2Fragment();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3Fragment();
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid tab position");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the taking time and posting this answer. It helped :)

Comment: I was searching for the Same problem Whole day. Thanks! Its resolved.

Comment: _/\_ _/\_ You just saved me from quitting the development :P

Comment: Message to Android core team: The documentation on this is insufficient producing timethiefs in development if you are just a little unlucky.

Answer (score 12):

i added tab text and icon for each tab after calling `tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)`

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    TabLayout tabs=(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
    tabs.getTabAt(0).setText(getResources().getText(R.string.tab1));
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setText(getResources().getText(R.string.tab2));
```

Comment: Will it work If the `tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` is called after setting the tabs

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Kotlin and have spent an hour to find the bugs with this code.

```
var viewPager: ViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

...

adapter = TabAdapter(fragmentManager!!)
adapter.addFragment(Fragment1(), "Fragment 1")
adapter.addFragment(Fragment2(), "Fragment 2")

viewPager.adapter = adapter

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager)
```

I can compile this with no error, but the tab title is not showing until I realize the **viewpager** I assigned to the tabLayout is not **viewPager** (notice the capitalize 'P'). It's not producing error because kotlin will find any matching layout id, in this case "viewpager" which is a ViewPager but on another view.

Comment: `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager)` is where people basically forget..

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to define TabItem in XML instead of doing it programmatically. As you mentioned, this setupWithViewPager() call resets the text and icon of the tab items to null( It uses the same tab object, just resets its content). I used your approach but made it more reusable. Here is my code:

```
public class TabLayoutUtil {
    public static void setupTabLayoutWithViewPager(TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager viewPager) {
        ArrayList<Pair<CharSequence, Drawable>> tabsContentCopy= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tabsContentCopy.add(new Pair<>(tab != null ? tab.getText() : null, tab != null ? tab.getIcon() : null));
        }
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if (i<tabsContentCopy.size()) {
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText(tabsContentCopy.get(i).first);
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabsContentCopy.get(i).second);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tabLayout!!.setupWithViewPager(viewpager)
check this line it's pointing to right viewpager or not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34394590)