# Can't swipe between tabs in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm able to click the tabs to change, but nothing happens when I swipe. I don't see the coloured bar underneath the selected tab either.

Here's my code. I've largely followed [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/) tutorial, but I've changed `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this)` to `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this)` in StoriesActivity because the former is depreceated.

StoriesActivity:

```
public class StoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    //This is our tablayout
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stories);

        /* +++ START Intent +++ */
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        final int authorID = extras.getInt("author_id");
        final String authorName = extras.getString("author_name");
        Log.i("click", Integer.toString(authorID));
        /* +++ END Intent +++ */

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(authorName);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Collections"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Creating our pager adapter
        StoriesTabsAdapter adapter = new StoriesTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        //Adding adapter to pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

activity_stories.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/stories_list_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

StoriesTabsAdapter:

```
public class StoriesTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int mNumOfTabs;

    public StoriesTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                StoriesFragment tab1 = new StoriesFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                CollectionsFragment tab2 = new CollectionsFragment();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }

}
```

StoriesFragment:

```
public class StoriesFragment extends Fragment {

    public StoriesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private ListView storiesListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stories, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow below two points.

- Use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** for good approach.
- [**`setupWithViewPager`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager))

> If you're using a ViewPager together with this layout, you can call
>   setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) to link the two together. This layout
>   will be automatically populated from the PagerAdapter's page titles.

Secondly

```
_tablayoutOBJ.setupWithViewPager(_viewpagerOBJ); // After addOnTabSelectedListener .
```

For, Demo case you can visit [**`Material Design working with Tabs`**](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Given that there will only be two pages, why should I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Comment: @Sebastian Its updated. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter

Comment: I still don't understand. I have a limited number of fragments, so `FragmentPagerAdapter` suits best, right?

Comment: @Sebastian then use `FragmentPagerAdapter`. No problem.

Comment: Great, thanks. Adding that code has the effect of removing the text from my tabs - any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: @Sebastian now read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049076/tablayout-tabs-text-not-displaying

Comment: That's restored the tabs, but I'm still unable to swipe between them...

Comment: @Sebastian see https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Thank you! It's now swiping, but the final problem is there's no bar underneath the selected tab.

Comment: Yep, by implementing the last tutorial you posted. If you add it to the answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing to [setupWithViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) your TabLayout.

```
 mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
```

Regarding the problem of your text not to be appearing, try to move the code below straight after you **setupWithViewPager**

```
        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Collections"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding that line after `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);` has the effect of removing the text from my tabs.