# TabLayoutMediator not preserving TabItem attributes

Tags: android, android-tablayout, material-components-android, android-viewpager2

I have a simple setup using ViewPager2 and TabLayout with preset TabItems:

```
...

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/c0696D7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/palettesToggle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabBackground="@color/cEEEEEE"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/cFFFFFF"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabUnboundedRipple="true"
            app:tabIconTint="@color/palettes_icon_tint"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:icon="@drawable/palettes_layers" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:icon="@drawable/palettes_view" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:icon="@drawable/palettes_properties" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:icon="@drawable/palettes_blocks" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:icon="@drawable/palettes_blocks" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:icon="@drawable/palettes_settings" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs" />

...
```

and the following wiring code:

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager) { tab, position ->

        }.attach()
```

The following setup ignores the `TabItem` icon attribute, and I see empty tabs. It seems that `TabLayoutMediator` completely overrides the defined xml attributes and i must reset those attributes as part of the `TabConfigurationStrategy` callback.
Am I missing something?

Comment: have a look at this issue thanks  :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474349/tablayoutmediator-not-showing-custom-tabitem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method `TabLayoutMediator.attach()` [calls the method](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-beta02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator.java#L151) `tabLayout.removeAllTabs();` which **removes all tabs** and then adds tabs again.

Check also the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator):

> When creating an instance of this class, you **must supply** an implementation of `TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy` in which you set the text of the tab, and/or perform any styling of the tabs that you require.

Something like:

```
new TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
      @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
        //Configure your tabs...
        tab.setText(...);
        tab.setIcon(...);
      }
    }).attach();
```

or:

```
 TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpager,
    TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
        //Configure tabs..
        when (position) {
            0 -> { tab.text = "..."}
            1 -> { tab.text = "..."}
        }
    }).attach()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I'm actually asking if there is a way to preserve the default xml styling? as I would expect...

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg I don't think. Also the `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()` (old viewpager) removes all the tabs reading the data from the adapter.

Comment: So any configuration applied to the tabs in XML has to be specified once again programmatically? This is a violation of DRY.

Comment: This approach forces to code markup instead of using xml, weird implementation

Comment: Calling second attach on the same TabLayoutMediator will throw -> IllegalStateException("TabLayoutMediator is already attached"); For anyone wondering why do you need to call detach first.