# How to use custom tab item in TabLayout with ViewPager2 in Android , TabLayoutMediator not showing custom TabItem

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to generate custom tab view using tab layout android with view pager 2, but I'm unable to see generated tab items.

**layout.xml**

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userInfoContainer">


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/figma_48_dp"
                android:background="@color/darkBlack"
                app:tabBackground="@color/darkBlack"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white">
               <!--
                app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="16dp"
               app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white"-->

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:alpha="1"
                    android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_header" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   
                    android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_header" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
           
                    android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_header" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                
                    android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_header" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   
                    android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_header" />


            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:outlineProvider="bounds" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**Custom Tab View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/figma_27_dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/figma_18_dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/figma_18_dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_tab"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tab_label"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tab_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/figma_10_dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/figma_10_dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/figma_14_sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:fontFamily="@font/worksans_regular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tab_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**Kotlin Code**

```
 TabLayoutMediator(
            binding.tabLayout,
            binding.viewPager,
            TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->


                //binding custom tab view
                val tabBinding: CustomTabHeaderBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(binding.tabLayout.context),
                    R.layout.custom_tab_header, binding.tabLayout,
                    false
                )

                //Name of Tab (Home)
                tabBinding.tabLabel.text =
                    viewModel?.getTabsName()?.value!![position].tabName

                //Name of Tab (Home Icon)
                tabBinding.tabIcon.setImageResource(viewModel?.getTabsName()?.value!![position].tabIcon)


                tab.let {
                    it.customView = tabBinding.root
                }

                onTabSelected(tab)
                onTabUnselected(tab)

                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        tab.select()
                    }
                    homePager.itemCount - 1 -> {
                        // populateTabItem(ktradeMainViewModel?.getTabsName()?.value!![position])
                        val currentPage = 0
                        binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, true)

                    }
                    
                }
                //for first time initialization tab will call for each view , it basically delete tabs and re-create tabs
            }).attach()
```

the issue I'm facing is selected tab is not showing its attributes(UI Component)

**Generated Result**

[image: Generated Result]

**Desired Result**

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tab mode scrollable solved my issue .

app:tabMode="scrollable"

Comment: Please elaborate. Looks like a coincidence. Sure you haven't changed anything else?

Comment: yup haven't changed anything long set mode to scrollable and it worked for me. @TheincredibleJan